# Git post-receive hook should not send email by new branching push

Tags: windows, git, branch, githooks, git-post-receive

my git remote repository is created on windows. (Bonobo Git Server is installed.)

There is a standard origin/master branch in my remote-Repository.

And there is a post-receive hook to send a email notification.

For a normal commit(file is modified and pushed), it works great.

But for a new branching push,
( = no files are modified, just a new brach is for origin created and pushed)
no email notification or some other email notification should be send.

how can i check, the last push is only for new branching?
is there any option for `git log` for that?